# How to make the formula works in all sheets except the first in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel VBA Code like below that runs on all sheets in the workbook and works perfectly well:

```
 Sub MarkCells()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
     For Each ws In Worksheets
      With ws
      .Range("C4:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
     "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],List,1,FALSE)),""KEEP"",""TO DELETE"")"
  End With
 Next ws
End Sub
```

My question is, how do I make this formula to work in all sheets, EXCEPT the first one, in this case is named sheet 'Macros'? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
Option Explicit

Sub MarkCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Macros" Then
            With ws
                .Range("C4:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],List,1,FALSE)),""KEEP"",""TO DELETE"")"
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this

```
Sub MarkCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Macros" Then
            With ws
            .Range("C4:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],List,1,FALSE)),""KEEP"",""TO DELETE"")"
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

No one else has used the .Index from the Worksheets collection so here is one more.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MarkCells()
    Dim w As long
    For w=2 to Worksheets.count
        With Worksheets(w)
            .Range(.Cells(4, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = _
              "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(RC[-1], List, 0)), ""KEEP"", ""TO DELETE"")"
        End With    
    Next w
End Sub
```

There is an inherent problem with this method as the user could conceivably reorder the worksheets unless the structure of the workbook was protected.

MATCH is faster than the equivalent VLOOKUP.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, what do you mean by using MATCH here will be faster? Is it as in the term of the memory usage? Thanks!

Comment: It simply computes faster. Granted that you might need 50K rows and iterate a couple thousand times before a human noticed the difference but it is faster, even on a single column for both.

Comment: @user71812, 100K rows in each of 5 worksheets: original VLOOKUP formula 2.472167 second; equivalent MATCH formula (as above) 1.782958 seconds.

Comment: awesome, thanks for clarifying, will be using it now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub MarkCells()
Dim ws          As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "macros" Then     'Added
        With ws
            .Range("C4:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],List,1,FALSE)),""KEEP"",""TO DELETE"")"
        End With
    End If                          'Added
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That string comparison is case sensitive. You might need lcase(ws.Name).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Jeeped